# Foreign domain points to server and sends spam

Tags: dns, spam, mail

I do have a really weird one. I am running a webhosting server that is being blocked by certain providers that use Cloudmark. I contacted the customer support and they got back with an email header that is unfortunately sending spam.

```
Received: from sub.domain.example ([1.1.1.1(my servers ip)])
Subject: sven.n.nilsson,=?utf-8?q?=62=65=6b=72=c3=a4=66=74=61=20=64=69=74=74=20=64=65=6c=74=61=67=61=6e=64=65=2e=2e=21=21=21?=
From: =?utf-8?q?=53=77=65=64=69=73=68=20=6d=65=74=68=6f=64?=  <VNH9DI6HOW68YGD4AWRMSPB0VT7UWSHX5@gmail.com>
```

The header states, that the mail came from my server. But how is that possible, I do have a closed relay and there is no mailbox for that domain. Furthermore, the domain is pointing to my servers' IP. How can I prevent it from faking email headers and pointing to my servers' IP?

Comment: You say a webhosting server.  Are the only accounts on the server yours?

Comment: Check the files on your server, maybe someone uploaded a file that is allowing attackers to send emails from your server. Also you should be able to prevent it by setting correct SPF records on your domain

Comment: Thanks. Will check that.

Comment: And yes. It's only my accounts. But I'll definitely have look at the files if I can find anything suspicious

Answer (score 1):

First of all,

You would have a security breach, so please check your server or hosting account for security-related problems and then to mitigate the sending of spam emails (spoofed) from that domain(subdomain) create a TXT record (DNS) with the following.

`sub.domain.example   TXT   "v=spf1 -all"`

By doing this you're telling the whole internet that this subdomain is not intended to send mail, please do this even if you don't have a mailbox in your server.

Comment: How do you know it is a security breach?

Comment: He stated that the header of the sending email was coming from his server ip.

Comment: That doesn't necessarily mean a "security breach" unless you mean it in the most broad of terms.